# Why is this flow getting executed even when no input found in php?

Tags: php

I have a form from which I am getting all the inputs. When I change a input to something erroneous it still executes the loop and does the entry in my db. Say suppose there is a blank date; still it accepts it and doesnt break out of the loop. I dont understand why.

Here is what I did:

```
if(isset($_POST['amt'])){
    $trans_amt = $_POST['amt'];

    if(isset($_POST['date'])){
        $date = $_POST['date'];

        if(isset($_POST['mode'])){
            $mode = $_POST['mode'];

            $updateQuery = "UPDATE table SET date = '".$date."' WHERE mode = ".$mode;

            $updateQuery1 = "UPDATE table1 SET date1 = '".$date."' WHERE mode1 = ".$mode;
        }
        else{
             echo "Mode not found";
        }
    else{
        echo "Date not found";
    }
else{
    echo "Amount not found";
}
```

Heres the problem.. when i accidently change my

Comment: your code just do conditions and echo's strings.  Are you executing your query string somewhere on your code?

Comment: First Point: there is no mysql insertion code anywhere. Maybe you've written somewhere else. 
Second Point: your first two if statements are not closed.

Comment: @GauravRai Consider that I have my mysqli statements.. the data is going in the database properly. The only fault is of my chain of if-statements

Comment: According to your chain only last if statement will work, i.e if(isset($_POST['mode']))
SO it doesnt matter, you post amt and date or not. Format it and see, if it works

Comment: Echo your query on browser : you will check what is coming in $date variable. Run query in your db

Answer (score 1, accepted):

`isset` checks that variable is set, even if variable is empty (false, 0 or empty string) - it is still **set** and `isset` returns **true**.

For checking emptiness - use `empty` or compare to empty string `""`

```
if (!empty($_POST["some_var"])) 
if ($_POST["some_var"] != "")
```

References: [isset](http://php.net/isset) and [empty](http://php.net/empty)

Comment: isset checks for.. if the string is non-empty and not-null .. isn't it ?

Comment: `isset` checks for variable is set and not null. `Set` means that it has some value. `False` and `empty string` are values.

Comment: I works @u_mulder. Seems like I got confused between isset and empty()

Answer (score 1):

This is because in case of blank date, the `date` variable is still passed to your php script but blank. The `isset` function only checks
for null value. You need to use `empty` function, which will be true in case of blank input.

Comment: are you suggesting i remove isset and replace with empty?

Comment: Just a moment. I will check and I will let you know.